# How to stop Google from eating event texts

Tags: samsung, samsung-one-ui, samsung-messages

I am using Messages version 14.5.20.5. After the most recent automatic Android update (One UI 5.1), Google is eating texts that contain event links. An "add event" button briefly appears and then disappears. About 30% of the time, an event is added to my calendar but it doesn't contain any useful information (not even the link nor the name of the sender). So basically these texts are lost.

Presumably, Google was trying to implement a feature that would generate a useful calendar event from texts. I don't need such a feature. How can I turn it off? (Also how did I give Google the indication that I wanted this feature turned on in the first place?)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Based on checking the app version, looks like this is [Samsung's stock Messages app](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/samsung-electronics-co-ltd/samsung-messages/samsung-messages-14-5-20-5-release/), not Google Messages. Thus, it's very likely that Samsung added the feature, not Google.

Comment: @Andrew You're right, it appears to be a Samsung app. (Given that this is the case, why would an Android update cause it to start the Add Event behavior?) In any case, your solution appears to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Samsung UI feature of creating events from SMS was [discussed here](https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S21/quot-Add-Event-quot-in-text-messages/td-p/2234400) last year.

Based on a quick look, it appears you can (and should) disable it from the Settings > Advanced Features > Smart suggestions screen.

For a moment, I assumed there was an SMS standard that includes events in a Calendar-useful format, but it seems to be a simple script sniffing your SMS contents and trying to guess if this is an event-related text.